# How do I share the value of a variable to another component in react?

Tags: html, reactjs, properties, react-hooks, jsx

How can I pass variables around to different components? I have a hook in the `VariableWithData` component which then multiplies the state when a button is clicked. How do I transfer the data of the variable `multiplied` onto the component `NeedVariableData` so that I can display the value on the `<h1>` tag?

```
//src/app.js

export const app = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <VariableWithData />
      <NeedVariableData />
    </div>
  )
}

// src/components/VariableWithData.js

import { useState } from "react"

export const VariableWithData = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(2)

  function multiplyData(){
    const multiplied = state * 2;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="submit" onClick={multiplyData}/>
    </div>
  )
}

// src/components/NeedVariableData.js

export const NeedVariableData = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{multiplyData}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeronimoo, You can make use of Props if the component are in Parent & Child relationship. Or if you want to share data across the component then either you can use ```context``` and ```providers``` or you can make use of ```State```

Comment: Can you show me how to do it in this example? @HimanshuSaxena

Comment: Hi @Jeronimoo33, As I can see you have accepted the below answer, hope you have got your answer. If any more information is needed, please let us know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [lift the state up.](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

```js
import { useState } from "react"

export const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(2);

  const handleClick = {
    setCount(c => c * 2);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <VariableWithData onClick={handleClick} />
      <NeedVariableData multiplyData={count} />
    </div>
  )
}

// src/components/VariableWithData.js

export const VariableWithData = ({ onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}/>
    </div>
  )
}

// src/components/NeedVariableData.js

export const NeedVariableData = ({ multiplyData }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{multiplyData}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```